# gulp task runner giving error

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I am getting error while doing task runner for "gulp" file, my sample project is with Angular 2 and Asp.net Core.

I have "typings" folder is in place, which has below "typings.json" file,

{
  "resolution": "main",
  "tree": {
    "src": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/be0ba281b67575b3b626a6bbb15b152add97244e/core-js/core-js.d.ts",
    "raw": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160914114559",
    "typings": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/be0ba281b67575b3b626a6bbb15b152add97244e/core-js/core-js.d.ts"
  }
}

[image]

Below is my "gulp" file,

```js
/*
This file in the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gp_clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    gp_concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    gp_sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    gp_typescript = require('gulp-typescript'),
    gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');



// Define paths
var srcPaths = {
    app: ['Scripts/app/main.ts', 'Scripts/app/**/*.ts'],
    js: [
    'Scripts/js/**/*.js',
    'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
    'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
    'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
    'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
    'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js'
    ],
    js_angular: [
    'node_modules/@angular/**'
    ],
    js_rxjs: [
    'node_modules/rxjs/**'
    ]
};

var destPaths = {
    app: 'wwwroot/app/',
    js: 'wwwroot/js/',
    js_angular: 'wwwroot/js/@angular/',
    js_rxjs: 'wwwroot/js/rxjs/'
};

// Compile, minify and create sourcemaps all TypeScript files and place
//them to wwwroot/app, together with their js.map files.

gulp.task('app', ['app_clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src(srcPaths.app)
        .pipe(gp_sourcemaps.init())
        //.pipe(plugins.typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(gp_typescript(require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions))
        .pipe(gp_uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(gp_sourcemaps.write('/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPaths.app));
});

// Delete wwwroot/app contents
gulp.task('app_clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(destPaths.app + "*", { read: false })
    .pipe(gp_clean({ force: true }));
});

// Copy all JS files from external libraries to wwwroot/js
gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src(srcPaths.js_angular)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destPaths.js_angular));
    gulp.src(srcPaths.js_rxjs)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destPaths.js_rxjs));
    return gulp.src(srcPaths.js)
    // .pipe(gp_uglify({ mangle: false })) // disable uglify
    // .pipe(gp_concat('all-js.min.js')) // disable concat
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destPaths.js));
});

// Delete wwwroot/js contents
gulp.task('js_clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(destPaths.js + "*", { read: false })
    .pipe(gp_clean({ force: true }));
});

// Watch specified files and define what to do upon file changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch([srcPaths.app, srcPaths.js], ['app', 'js']);
});

// Global cleanup task
gulp.task('cleanup', ['app_clean', 'js_clean']);

// Define the default task so it will launch all other tasks
gulp.task('default', ['app', 'js', 'watch']);
```

Below are the 67 error,

```js
C:\01Work\OpenGameList\src\OpenGameListWebApp> cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\01Work\OpenGameList\src\OpenGameListWebApp" --color --gulpfile "C:\01Work\OpenGameList\src\OpenGameListWebApp\Gulpfile.js" default
[11:39:57] Using gulpfile C:\01Work\OpenGameList\src\OpenGameListWebApp\Gulpfile.js
[11:39:57] Starting 'app_clean'...
[11:39:57] Starting 'js'...
[11:39:57] Starting 'watch'...
[11:39:57] Finished 'watch' after 37 ms
[11:39:58] Finished 'app_clean' after 543 ms
[11:39:58] Starting 'app'...
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(46,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(39,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(347,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(348,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(19,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(21,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(15,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(16,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(31,124): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts(424,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts(13,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(40,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(42,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.d.ts(45,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(35,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(36,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_element.d.ts(33,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_query.d.ts(24,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_view.d.ts(29,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_view.d.ts(52,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/compile_view.d.ts(54,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(106,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(122,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(148,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(150,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(28,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(88,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(88,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(3,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(5,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(5,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(9,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(13,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(16,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(103,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(51,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(14,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts(45,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/http/src/url_search_params.d.ts(46,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(79,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(97,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts(18,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(3,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(5,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(5,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(9,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(13,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(16,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(103,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(68,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(40,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts(41,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(8,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,79): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
C:/01Work/OpenGameList/src/OpenGameListWebApp/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[11:40:03] TypeScript: 76 semantic errors
[11:40:03] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[11:40:03] Finished 'js' after 6.2 s
[11:40:03] Finished 'app' after 5.69 s
[11:40:03] Starting 'default'...
[11:40:03] Finished 'default' after 8.93 μs
```

Comment: Interesting, getting much the same. Receiving 90 errors that all appear to almost appear as if Angular was not imported correctly, every error is similar, all relating to a method that's not found, such as Map and Set in the lang.d.ts file etc... That's even happening running the example solutions by chapter downloaded from the Packt website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't include any information related to your TypeScript version, but I'll assume it's TS >=2.0.

In this case, you need to include `@types/core-js` in your package.json. In addition to that, you need to point core-js types in your tsconfig.json (or either tsconfig-aot.json)

`"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types"
]`

If you specify all types manually, then...

`"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types"
],
"types": [
  "core-js", ...(other types you manually specify)
]`

Hope it helps.